# Changing timezone of the date to UTC on API Level 21

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have a Date and I need to change timezone of this date to UTC. The code below does not work.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(dateLocal.getTime());

    return new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

On the Stackoverflow all examples return either a String or use API 26. How can I solve my problem on the Android API 21?

Comment: A `java.util.Date` doesn't have a time zone, it is just a thin wrapper around milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC. Time zone is only relevant when parsing or printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Date getDateInUtc() {
        String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        Date dateToReturn = null;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
        String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        try {
            dateToReturn = dateFormat.parse(utcTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dateToReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cal.getTime();`  which returns date

Comment: timezone doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

The same result you can get without SimpleDateFormat:

```
public Date dateInUtc(Date input) {
    Calendar inputCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    inputCalendar.setTime(input);
    TimeZone timeZone = inputCalendar.getTimeZone();
    long timeInUtc = input.getTime() - timeZone.getRawOffset();

    Calendar outputCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    outputCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInUtc);
    return outputCalendar.getTime();
}
```